# Export current part of a map

Tags: javascript, c#, dictionary, export

I have an Openstreetmap map, it contains the original zoom sidebar from openstreetmap.org, but I want to export the current part of the map, that I see. I want a picture from the map. 
Is there an easy way to this? Maybe, can I embed the original export/share sidebar or other way with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where you have this map, and so the options available to you may differ depending on what is available through that display of OpenStreetMap.

If you are at http://www.openstreetmap.org then look at the icons at the right of the map/page. The "share" icon (an arrow jumping out of a box) gives image export features.

If you are not at openstreetmap.org then try and work out the co-ordinates or location that you are viewing and then find these at OpenStreetMap.org.

There are multiple ways to generate an image from OpenStreetMap data. The best one will depend on your needs, your resources, and if you want to do this manually yourself or offer it as a service to others. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_on_Paper

**Copyright:** remember that you need to include attribution when you use OpenStreetMap. Not all image creation features do this by default or even include it as a filter. Information and the appropriate text can be found at http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

Comment: thanks, I guess I can make it with these informations